# Why does the Hadoop incompatible namespaceIDs issue happen?

Tags: hadoop

This is a fairly well-documented error and the fix is easy, but does anyone know why Hadoop datanode NamespaceIDs can get screwed up so easily or how Hadoop assigns the NamespaceIDs when it starts up the datanodes?

Here's the error:

```
2010-08-06 12:12:06,900 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /Users/jchen/Data/Hadoop/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 773619367; datanode namespaceID = 2049079249
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1368)
```

This seems to even happen for single node instances.

Comment: could you please tell what the fix is?????

Comment: From a link below, but this is to the specific section of the guide that describes the fix: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#javaioioexception-incompatible-namespaceids

Comment: This is why: "When the name-node reformats it generates a new namespaceID.
Now if the cluster starts with the reformatted name-node, and not reformatted data-nodes
the data-nodes will fail with
java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs " https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-107

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Namenode generates new namespaceID every time you format HDFS. I think this is possibly to differentiate current version and previous version. You can always rollback to previous version if something is not proper which may not be possible if namespaceID is not unique for every formatted instance.

NamespaceID also connects namenode and datanodes. Datanodes bind themselves to namenode through namespaceID

Comment: thanks for the answer. Any idea how to remove this inconsistency?

Answer (score 8):

this problem is well explained and helped in the following [fine guide](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/#java-io-ioexception-incompatible-namespaceids)

Comment: It's a fine guide, and it explains how to fix the problem, but not what causes it nor how to avoid it...though it does link to the bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-107 formerly known as http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1212

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this too, and then I tried putting my configuration in `hdfs-site.xml` instead of `core-site.xml`.

Seems to stop and start without that error now.

[EDIT, 2010-08-13]

Actually this is still happening, and it is caused **by** formatting.

If you watch the VERSION files when you do a format, you'll see (at least I do) that the namenode gets assigned a new namespaceID, but the data node does not.

Quick solution is to delete the VERSION for the datanode before format.

[TIDE, 2010-08-13]

Comment: where is defined VERSION?

Comment: It is located here tmp/dfs/data/current/VERSION

Answer (score 0):

When I formatted my HDFS I also encountered this error. Apart from datanode not getting started, the jobtracker also won't start.
For the datanode I manually changed the namespaceid; but for the jobtracker one has to create the /mapred/system (as hdfs user) directory and change its owner to mapred. The jobtracker should start running then after the format.

Comment: How did you change namespace ID?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error "Incompatible namespaceIDs in /home/hadoop/data/dn",

I have four data nodes in the cluster, after starting start-dfs.sh only one datanode used to come up, SO the solution was to stop service in nn and jt and remove dn configuration drom hdfs-site in all  datanodes, remove the dn file(/home/hadoop/data/dn) and format the namenode.
Then again add the datanode properties in hdfs-site in all datanodes and format namenode onceagain.  try starting services now all data nodes will be up surely