# Incompatible build versions error in Hadoop slave node

Tags: hadoop

My Hadoop cluster was running without any mistake. I don't know what has changed but when I try to start Hadoop components with start-all.sh command from master, I check running processes with jps command and see that DataNode does not work in slave node.

The datanode log is below. Versions of Hadoop installation (1.0.4) are the same on the machines in the cluster. I could not find how to solve the problem.

```
2013-09-18 09:35:21,638 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = noon101/10.240.20.30
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
STARTUP_MSG:   build =  -r ; compiled by 'hduser' on Wed May 29 10:55:16 EEST 2013
************************************************************/
2013-09-18 09:35:21,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-09-18 09:35:21,761 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-09-18 09:35:21,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-09-18 09:35:21,762 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2013-09-18 09:35:21,867 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-09-18 09:35:21,869 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-09-18 09:35:26,964 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Incompatible build versions: namenode BV = 1393290; datanode BV =
2013-09-18 09:35:27,070 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible build versions: namenode BV = 1393290; datanode BV =
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.handshake(DataNode.java:566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:362)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1582)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1682)

2013-09-18 09:35:27,071 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at noon101/10.240.20.30
************************************************************/
```

Below are part of datanode logs.
Slave node:

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = noon101/10.240.20.30
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
STARTUP_MSG:   build =  -r ; compiled by 'hduser' on Wed May 29 10:55:16 EEST 2013
```

Master node:

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = noon102/10.240.20.32
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
```

When looking at the nodes, I see version and build values are different. Even if this is the problem, I still do not know how to solve it.

Comment: look like u may have some version problem with JAVA for your hadoop version.

Comment: Both are using same version of Java. I checked JAVA_HOME value in $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425688/why-does-the-hadoop-incompatible-namespaceids-issue-happen?rq=1

Comment: its comptely different problem.

Comment: @JtheRocker my problem is not incompatible "NamespaceId", but incompatible "build version"

Comment: Oops! My bad. Sorry, didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally would happen if there was any kind of change to the conf directory on the Master Name node. Are you sure there wasn't some kind of an ant script which ran or something which messed with the jar files in the 'lib' directory of Hadoop?

This issue seems to be fairly prevalent. The following link has a clear step-by-step instruction of how you can salvage the situation. The gist of it being, you try to copy the conf directory of the Datanode to Master node after backing it up.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/22499

See if this helps.

Comment: I solved my problem by following and slightly changing steps in the link. My master node was working but DataNode in slave node was not running. I copied the hadoop folder from master to slave node and changed conf/slaves and conf/masters files in slave node. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: The link you provided solved a similar problem that I had with incompatible build versions/checksums between the jobtracker (on master) and tasktracker (on slave). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it's solved! I received the error "Incompatible build versions: namenode BV = ; datanode BV = 985326" many times as I had many < property > ... < /property > tabs under  ... < configuration > tab in mapred-site.xml. I had to make sure all configurations are same in all nodes (master+slaves). If a single value in < property > ... < /property > tab differs from one node to another, you are likely to see the Incompatible Build Version error.

So here is the summary:
1) Make sure you have same hadoop version in all nodes.
2) Make sure you have same all *-site.xml are same in all nodes that is you use same configuration in core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, and hdfs-site.xml.

Good Luck!