# Hadoop put command throws - could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop, I am trying to do pseudo distributed mode setup on my ubuntu machine and facing an issue with `hadoop put` command. My configuration details are available in this post --> [What the command "hadoop namenode -format" will do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143409/what-the-command-hadoop-namenode-format-will-do)

Now I am trying to add some files to HDFS using below commands:

```
hadoop fs –mkdir /user/myuser

hadoop fs -lsr /

$ ./hadoop fs -lsr /
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /tmp/hadoop-myuser
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /tmp/hadoop-myuser/dfs
-rw-r--r--   1 myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /tmp/hadoop-myuser/dfs/name
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /tmp/hadoop-myuser/mapred
drwx------   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:12 /tmp/hadoop-myuser/mapred/system
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:04 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - myuser supergroup          0 2014-11-26 16:06 /user/myuser
```

Now I am running the `put` command but getting exception like this:

```
$ ./hadoop fs -put example.txt .
14/11/26 16:06:19 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)

14/11/26 16:06:19 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
14/11/26 16:06:19 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/myuser/example.txt" - Aborting...
put: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
14/11/26 16:06:19 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /user/myuser/example.txt
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/myuser/example.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
```

Can someone please help me how can I fix this issue?

**Solution to the issue:**

Based on answers provided I am able to solve the issue by following below steps:

1) Stop all services:

```
./stop-all.sh
```

2) Delete the data directory:

```
rm -rf /tmp/hadoop-myuser/dfs/data/
```

3) Start the services:

```
./start-all.sh
```

4) Then put the file into HDFS:

```
./hadoop fs -put example.txt .
```

Comment: what happens with the fully qualified hdfs name i.e. `./hadoop fs -put ./example.txt /user/myuser/example.txt`?

Comment: @davek, I am getting same error message.

Comment: Did you check "dfs.replication" at "hdfs-site.xml" has minimum 1. I think you may put 0 replication. and also check all hadoop services are still running or not?

Comment: @ǨÅVËĔŊRĀǞĴĄŅ, The dfs.replications is set as 1 in my xml file. How can I check is some hadoop service is down? Can you please tell me.

Comment: check using JPS command..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the data node problem.
**Start your datanode** and do the operation now

Comment: If this answer is correct for you means, accept this as answer. So that others can easily find this.

Comment: can you please tell me how to check if datanode is down and also how start the data-node?

Comment: using command JPS you can view which hadoop services running and you can start datanode by hadoop datanode comamnd under Hadoop_home/bin path

Comment: Great, using JPS I can see that datanode is down. Now when I try to start datanode I am gettinf error as : `14/11/26 17:32:32 ERROR datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /tmp/hadoop-chaitanya/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 1198050192; datanode namespaceID = 976283118
`

Comment: stop namenode and delete the datanode directory in dfs.datanode.data.dir, then start namenode and datanode.

Comment: can you please tell me command to stop only namenode service?

Comment: just close your terminal window where namenode runs

Comment: I am just having single terminal where I ran start-all.sh to start the services, and I know the command stop-all.sh that stops all the services, can you please tell me if there is a command to stop single service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65688/discussion-between-rengasamy-and-user3181365).

Answer (score 1):

Did you check **"dfs.replication"** at **"hdfs-site.xml"** has minimum 1. I think you may put 0 replication.

And also check all hadoop services are running or not?

To check Running status:
run `JPS` command

**To start the service individually:**
Goto `...\hadoop\bin\`

```
start hadoop {datanode \ namenode}
start yarn {nodemanager \ resourcemanager}
```

Comment: I am getting error while starting datanode as - 14/11/26 17:32:32 ERROR datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible namespaceIDs in /tmp/hadoop-chaitanya/dfs/data: namenode namespaceID = 1198050192; datanode namespaceID = 976283118

Comment: This will be help you [Incombatible NamespaceID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3516422/3452185)